# how to give a unique variable name for each result?

Tags: php

I want to give each output a unique variable name so I can use it anyway I want Any help?

```
<?php  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $var = $row['field_name'];
        echo $var."<br>"; 
        // Outputs name1 name2 etc.,
    }
?>
```

Comment: the same way you did this: `$var = $row['field_name'];`. Will that not work?

Comment: you can use `extract($row)`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Use array, add square brackets: $var[] = $row['field_name']; and echo end($var);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to store them in an array, unless you want to go to the trouble of creating dynamic variable names.

```
<?php
$names = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $var = $row['field_name'];
    echo $var."<br>"; 
    // Outputs name1 name2 etc.,
    $names[] = $var;
}
echo $names[0];
echo $names[1];
// etc.
```

Comment: Sir, why it is a  "troublesome"?

Comment: Because you need to get a counter, create dynamic variable names, and then when you're done you have no easy way to iterate through your collected data.

Comment: This works for me..tnx, gonna find solution to the problem you mentioned, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $var = array();
            while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $var['name1'] = $row['field_name_1'];
                $var['name2'] = $row['field_name_2'];
            }
        echo $var['name1']." ".$var['name2'];
        ?>
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Sir, there is only 1 field name and it will echo all it contents which is the results, the said results is the one I want to give a unique variable name.

Answer (score 0):

As Sahil said in comments `extract()` is a good option.

```
extract($row)
```

`$row` is an associative array. This function treats keys as variable names and values as variable values.For each key/value pair it will create a variable in the current symbol table

Read more about `extract()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
<?php  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM db";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        extract($row);
         //now you can echo each value using its field name
        echo $fieldname1;
        echo $fieldname2;        

    }
?>
```

Comment: Sir, there is only 1 field name and it will echo all it contents which is the results, the said results is the one I want to give a unique variable name.

Comment: So, your each row has only one column and you want each row in result in separate variable?

Comment: There is an primary id and name, 2 fields, I will output the name but assign it in seperate unique variable name.